# ffmpeg rtmp and overlay png's to rtmp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

Hi im trying to get one or more png's as an overlay in bottom left of video
but im not sure how to achieve it.

exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "rtmp://urltortmp" -f image2 -i 1.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1920k -b:a 64k -vf "scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset superfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/std 2>>/var/log/nginx/ffmpeg-std.log;

error from output how do i map it ? with one png or more.. want then to be like a slideshow

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://urlrtmp':
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: true
    displayWidth    : 2304
    displayHeight   : 1296
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 138709.448000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 2304x1296, 13 fps, 12 tbr, 1k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
Input #1, image2, from '1.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 300x45 [SAR 2800:2800 DAR 20:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Filtergraph 'scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.



// Anders




tested to use filter complex
```

Comment: This works but the live feed is like 1.5 min inbehind  and also very high cpu load on the intel nuc
when i use -c copy to rtmp its just like 10 sec of delay :)

exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "rtmp://jurrlrtmp" -f image2 -i 1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1920k -b:a 64k -tune zerolatency -preset superfast -crf 23  -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/std 2>>/var/log/nginx/ffmpeg-std.log;

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by creating a mp4 file of the png's
and added -stream_loop -1

```
exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg -threads 1 -i "rtmp://urltortmp" -stream_loop -1 -i slider.m
p4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=20:main_h-overlay_h-80" -c:v h264 -c:a aac -b:v 1920k -b:a 64k -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/std 2>>/var/log/nginx/ffmpeg-std.log;
```